# jQuery next() should be simple not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to do what seems like should be a simple jQuery effect, I've used similar code before, but I am unable to get it to work. I am still pretty new to this, it's probably something super easy, but I have spent quite some time, I don't see it.

My hmtl is like this

```
<a href="#" class="trigger">details</a>
<div class="details">       
  <?echo $data['referral'];?>
  <a href="#">update</a>
</div>
```

My jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
$('.trigger').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll(".details:first").toggle('slow', function () {
    });
  });
 });
```

I have also tried:
    $(this).next().toggle('slow', function ()

The only thing that will work is 
     $('.details').toggle('slow', function () 
but that opens all the details tabs on my page, not very useful.

Would greatly appreciate any tips!

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/r29ys/).

Comment: Is this your actual code? As SLaks pointed out, it should work given what you presented.

Comment: two notes, one if your div is ALWAYS comes after your link then just use `next()`, two no need for the call back if you're not going to use it `toggle('slow');`

Comment: actually three notes, after your animation `return false;` :-)

Comment: It is my actual code, except I removed a bunch of php inside the details div for clarity; removed code just displays data. I'm using codeigniter, I really hope that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Rebecca: Then there's some other issue. If `.details` is a sibling after `.trigger`, your selector should find it. Check for invalid HTML markup. Perhaps look at your HTML using Chrome's (or some other browser's) developer tools to see if it looks like it is rendering the way you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the answers! My problem did seem to be the result of using Codeigniter, I had white space around my a and div tags, and when I looked at the generated html in firebug, as Patrick suggested, the white space was encased in p tags that were not in my code, like:

```
 <p>
 <a href="#" class="trigger">details</a>
 </p>
```

So I would have had to use something like parent().next().child(). I removed the white space, and the elements became siblings again and all is well. Now I need to figure out how to stop codeigniter from doing that!

Thanks again!

Rebecca

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it